# Android launcher focused around Social Networking

Tags: gratis, android, social-networks, launcher

I am looking for an Android Launcher that is focused on social networking. For example, for any selected text, a popup should come up saying something like 'Tweet | Post', or similar.

Facebook chat should be integrated (preferably with the Chat Heads :)

I would like this to be free, I don't care if it's 'freemium' as long as the above features are in it.

Basically, any launcher with social networking *integrated* into the launcher.

It needs to be compatible with Android 4.1.1 (Jelly Bean). If you need to know, I have a Sony Xperia E